# Getting an error with XCHTMLReport from fast lane

Tags: fastlane

stuck on an error we are getting from fastlane on a new node server trying to use xchtmlreport: (OSX 14.2 node)

xchtmlreport binary not installed! [https://github.com/TitouanVanBelle/XCTestHTMLReport�[0m](https://github.com/TitouanVanBelle/XCTestHTMLReport

But, I have installed this on the box using brew install, it comes back and says it's on version 2.4.1.

Not sure if there is something I need to add to my fastfile of jenkins file to help fast lane find this service.

Here is the call we are making in fast lane:

desc "Generate HTML Test Report" lane :runHTMLReport do xchtmlreport() end

Any hints welcome, thank you in advance!